# Metric units convertor without input method - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a simple function so information about range of a car can be converted by one click to metric units. When I am using input method I convert it into floating point number and after simple calculation I get a result. Problem is I don't want to give visitors an ability to change numbers. Numbers should be directly from database, not touched by anyone.

What I am missing with my method of converting number directly from paragraph?

```
<button type="button" id="fButton2">Convert to metric units</button>
<p id="valToConvertKm2">
10 miles
</p>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

jQuery

```
$("#fButton2").click(function()
         {
           var inputVal1 = $("#valToConvertToKm2");
             var outputVal1 = $("p#result2");
         // read value entered by user
         // convert it from string to number
         var initialVal1 = parseFloat(inputVal1.val());
         console.log(initialVal1);
         // bulletproof
         if(isNaN(initialVal1))
         {
             window.alert("Enter a valid number! \nTry again!");
             inputVal1.val("");
             outputVal1.val("");
         }
         else
         {
             // calculate it, to 2 decimal points
             var calculatedVal1 = ( 1.609344 *initialVal1 ).toFixed(0);
             // display square
             outputVal1.val(calculatedVal1);

             $('p#result2').text(calculatedVal1).append(" km");

         }
         }
         );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z67cyywp/23/

Comment: you can put `readonly` property on the input `<input readonly>`

Comment: If I would adjust styling so it wouldn't look like input field then it might work. Isn't there a more elegant solution of retrieving data than input though? @MrNew

Comment: its not a styling, its an attribute of an `input`. It would still look like an input they just can't edit the content https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp, well you'll need to do an ajax call to your DB to retrieve your data and display them in the input. What kind of DB is it?

Comment: I am using php echoing to display numbers `<p class="miles"><?php echo $carOne->range_mph;?> miles</p>`. MariaDB